# Blob Url for Audio Element Source

Tags: html, blob, mobile-safari, html5-audio, microsoft-edge

I need to use a blob url for the audio element source, and it is not working on Edge or Safari; however it works in Chrome and Firefox. So basically something like this:

```
    <audio id="audio" controls>
           <source id="source" 
                   src="blob:https://example.com/a7e38943-559c-43ea-b6dd-6820b70ca1e2" 
                   type="audio/ogg"/>
    </audio>
```

is not working on Safari or Edge. Any workarounds?

You can also check this fiddle for example and try it different browsers:
https://jsfiddle.net/sanddune/uubnnr0w/

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks.